# Python-ValueError: the environment variable is longer than 32767 characters

Tags: python, environment-variables, gurobi

I'm solving a MILP problem with python and Gurobi,and the exact method is Lagrangian relaxation.So I need to run the program iteratively to get the optimal solution.But it will terminate after around 200 iterations,like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlnOS.png)
I have no idea how to deal with it.Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that each iteration, it just appends the *GUROBI_HOME* path to your environment variable. This makes the environment variable longer and longer until it finally breaks because of an error. I would change the line in `solvers.py, actualSolve()` so it first checks whether your environment variable already contains the *GUROBI_HOME* path.

Answer (score 0):

Windows has a 1024 character limit on environmental variables and this error is not unusual in Windows therefore. You can try reinstalling python and your libraries directly in a folder on your C:\ drive and set the environmental variables to the new path.

You could try to first get it running on one PC, then use pyinstaller to create an executable of your code and then run that executable on those other PCs. Or is it somehow very important to run directly from source code on the other PCs?

Comment: I edited my answer in response to your comment. My advise is to first get it running on a single PC and then try to move on to other machines.